# Compiler complains when I iterate Non-Generics Map in Java

Tags: java, generics

I meet weired problem when I iterate a Non-Generics Map in Java

```
Map map=new HashMap();
for (Map.Entry entry:map.entrySet()){

}
```

But compiler complains and says that "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Map.Entry"
When I change the Map type to Generics, it can work

```
Map<Object,Object> map=new HashMap<Object,Object>();
for (Map.Entry entry:map.entrySet()){

}
```

It makes me confused, anybody know what's the reason ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use a raw type, like you do here with `Map`, all generics is turned off, so `entrySet()` just returns a bare `Set` type (not `Set<Map.Entry whatever>`), which, if you iterate over it, you can only get `Object`s out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to JDK1.5 `map.entrySet()` returned a `Set` (of `Map.Entry`, but you couldn't tell directly).

```
Set entries = map.entrySet();
Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.iterator().next();  // <-- notice the cast!
```

Answer (score -1):

**Why doesn't this work ?**

It depends on your compiler.

With javac 1.6.0_20 on a Mac, I didn't have any problem.

Maybe as @newacct suggested, generics were turned of for your extended for statement. But as it depends on your compiler (and not the JLS) it's not really easy to know why exactly.

**How can this can be change to work ?**

Map.Entry is a generic class, so if you choose to have generics in your application, you should use them everywhere.

```
Map<Object,Object> map=new HashMap<Object,Object>();
for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry:map.entrySet()){

}
```

Comment: @aioobe, updated, in fact it compiles on some compilers (here javac), without even a warning.