# How to get key and value only from a JSONObject, Java

Tags: java, json

So i got this code here:

```
public JSONObject serializeMessageToJson(TextMessage m) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put(m.getSender(), m.getMessage());
    return obj;
}
```

that basically turns my message into this:

```
{"D":"dsdsa"}
{"D":"dsadas"}
{"D":"dsadas"}
```

in the file system i send it into.

Now, assuming i use the scanner go get that string up there like this:

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
String ser = scan.nextLine();
```

how do i parse this object inside the file system into a new Message(String "D", String "dsdsa")?

Thanks in advance

As Adrian said tried putting it like this:

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
                String ser = scan.nextLine();
                JsonParserFactory factory= JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
                com.json.parsers.JSONParser parser = factory.newJsonParser();
                Map jsonMap = parser.parseJson(ser);
                Set senderSet= jsonMap.keySet();
                String sender = senderSet.toString();
                String message = (String)jsonMap.get(sender);
                msg= new TextMessage(message, sender,"",0);
                System.out.println(msg.getMessage()+msg.getSender());
```

and unfortunately i get null on the msg:

```
null[D]
null[D]
null[D]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some library like [quick-json](https://code.google.com/p/quick-json/) and parse it like this:

```
JsonParserFactory factory=JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
JSONParser parser=factory.newJsonParser();
Map jsonMap=parser.parseJson(jsonString);
```

Once you have the `Map` you just have to get the key and value.

```
for ( Map.Entry<String, String> entry : jsonMap.entrySet()) {
    String sender= entry.getKey();
    String message= entry.getValue();
    TextMessage msg = new TextMessage(message, sender, "",0);
    System.out.println(msg.getMessage()+msg.getSender());
}
```

**EDIT:**

The code above breaks with a mismatch error, according with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3904461/4224126) it is a compiler fault. You can try to cheat it:

```
Set<Entry> entries = jsonMap.entrySet();
for ( Entry entry : entries) {
    String sender= entry.getKey();
    String message= entry.getValue();
    TextMessage msg = new TextMessage(message, sender, "",0);
    System.out.println(msg.getMessage()+msg.getSender());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but either i'm doing something wrong or the message is not entering correctly in the map.

Comment: What are you getting on your jsonMap?

Comment: {D=dsdsa}

{D=dsadas}

{D=dsadas}

Comment: ok, it seems the parser is workig fine. I've updated my answer, I don't know if this is the exactly behaviour you want but I think is something similar.

Comment: It's probably what i want, the thing is, now i get a type mismatch  from Object to Entry<String, String> at for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : jsonMap.entrySet()) { more specifically at the jsonMap.entrySet(), tried using KeySet() also didn't work,a also tried to change the map but no luck.

Comment: It is getting interesting :). According with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3904461/4224126) it is a compiler fault. We can try `Set<Entry> entries = jsonMap.entrySet();` before the `for` loop and iterate over ´entries`. I'll edit the answer to include it.